# Can I use "has" after being a noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, gerund-phrases

I have a question about verb agreement. Can I use "has" after [*being* +  noun]?

For example, is *has* the correct form of the verb in the following sentence?

> Being a celebrity has  both some advantages and some disadvantages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gerund Phrase as Subject](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/gerund-phrase-as-subject)

Comment: I get 32,400 results for ["being a celebrity has"](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=%22being+a+celebrity+has%22). Have you tried it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think that this question is asking about whether the gerund-participle can be used as a Subject, but rather about what form of the verb  should be used after Subjects like these. I'm taking that from the OP's tag, which says "verb agreement"

Comment: Yes, Araucaria , i would like to know sub-verb agreement.

Comment: Agreement has been covered at [entertaining multiple goals makes/make a person's life stressful](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71335/entertaining-multiple-goals-makes-make-a-person-s-life-stressful).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not a very good question to dupe to though, imo, because the OP is clearly confused and doesn't understand the difference between singular and plural agreement. I'd have thought it would be better to close that as a dupe of this one. That one's also narrower in scope. This question is, at least, clear - and has the potential for better answers for future reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's my opinion, but I don't think it is a good idea to close it as duplicate. I think the question is general reference and the OP should include his research effort and state what he understands from his research and what bothers him most.

Comment: @Araucaria If the issue is  'the OP is clearly confused and doesn't understand the difference between singular and plural agreement', the question is certainly _too basic_ for ELU. Your answer hinges on clauses taking singular agreement; with the gerund-participial [CGEL] clause OP asks about here, this has certainly been addressed at the previous thread. If your answer is superior (and it may well be), the place to post it is in the original thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, there are two OP's going on here! I was referring to the OP of the *other* thread, who clearly thought that *make* was singlular and *makes* was plural!  This OP understands the difference, but is unsure what agreement is used with a clause - which seems to be a useful enough question to have here on EL&U, imo.

Comment: @Araucaria The two downvotes for the question here are not mine (though obviously one close-vote is).

Comment: Another relevant question: [Subject with a Gerund: “is” or “are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18815)

Answer (score 6):

> Being a celebrity has both some advantages and some disadvantages.

The Subject of this sentence is the clause *being a celebrity*. Clauses functioning as Subject take singular verb agreement. It doesn't matter what type of clause it is. The Original Poster's example sentence happens to use a subject-less gerund-participle clause. This clause also happens to be a declarative clause. However, clauses of almost any description will take singular verb agreement:

- [What the elephants found] is not important.
- [Whether to go or not] is not the most important question.
- [That the students never finish their essays] really annoys me.
- [For Bob to say that] is extraordinarily hypocritical.
- [To err] is human.
- [Eating vegetables] is good for you.

So in the Original Poster's example the form of the verb *has* is completely grammatical.

Comment: You've convinced me that, on balance, a (much) better answer outweighs the duplication issues. I've checked quite a few 'singular or plural after gerund-participial' questions here, and _all_ of them claim that the g-p 'is singular' (obviously, if it's become count it's deverbal) when they should stick with 'takes singular agreement'. I've tinkered with your answer so as to be able to rescind the -1.

Comment: +1 It might be worthwhile (just to avoid the need for future clarification) to provide an example or two in which the subject of the subordinate clause is plural.

Comment: If I might express a mild reservation, I don't think your examples show how strong an attraction there is to the singular in these cases. I think we'd still say *Whatever Bertha and Tabitha did **was** amazing* even though we have two people doing multiple things. We'd only go to the plural with a different structure -- *Things Bertha did **were** amazing*. (Is that right?) Again, *Their eating vegetables **is** good for them* even though multiple people are eating multiple things. *To err and to persist in error **is** human* still works, I think, but it could go the other way.

Comment: @StoneyB, Deadrat, Some helpful feedback. Thanks! Will tend to it tomorrow :) Btw, Deadrat, as SB also said, I do indeed need better examples with plural subjects. The *Things Bertha did were amazing*, example is as you say a different structure, where it is an NP headed by *things* with a modifying relative clause. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @deadrat Aargh. Your example just made me realise that I made a big rubharb in my first example, which was also an NP, not a clause. Have put a (rather ambiguous) sticking plaster on it till tomorrow. Am trying to do some uni work ... .